# Why does a static website hosted on AWS S3 require CORS to be enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Reading this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html it states that :

> Your users load the website endpoint: http://**website.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com**
> Now you want to use JavaScript on the webpages that are stored in this bucket to be able to make authenticated GET and PUT requests against the same bucket by using the Amazon S3 API endpoint for the bucket, **website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com**. ***A browser would normally block JavaScript from allowing those requests***

Why would a browser require CORS to be enabled for requests back to the same server that hosts the static content ? i.e. website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Comment: I can understand confusion, it could be rewritten better. 
S3 REST API endpoints are of the format `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and website endpoints are `website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
When we host website and do GET/PUT requests, they call s3 api with param as bucket name (website) and path. Hence, CORS is needed.

Comment: Ah - thank you that makes total sense then.  If you want to make this comment an answer i'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand confusion, it could be rewritten better.

S3 REST API endpoints are of the format `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and website endpoints are `website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
When we host website and do GET/PUT requests, they call s3 api with param as bucket name (website) and path. Hence, CORS is needed.